# Is libgcrypt thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, libgcrypt

Is library libgcrypt thread-safe one? In case that I don't divide resources of this library between threads, but create different context in every thread. C++ programming language.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Multi_002dThreading.html) says, `libgcrypt` is thread-safe with conditions:

> As mentioned earlier, the Libgcrypt library is thread-safe if you
>   adhere to the following requirements:
>
> - If you use pthread and your applications forks and does not directly call exec (even calling stdio functions), all kind of
>     problems may occur. Future versions of Libgcrypt will try to cleanup
>     using pthread_atfork but even that may lead to problems. This is a
>     common problem with almost all applications using pthread and fork.
> - The function gcry_check_version must be called before any other function in the library. To achieve this in multi-threaded programs,
>     you must synchronize the memory with respect to other threads that
>     also want to use Libgcrypt. For this, it is sufficient to call
>     gcry_check_version before creating the other threads using Libgcrypt1.
> - Just like the function gpg_strerror, the function gcry_strerror is not thread safe. You have to use gpg_strerror_r instead.

With an additional caveat:

> At least this is true for POSIX threads, as pthread_create is a
>   function that synchronizes memory with respects to other threads.
>   There are many functions which have this property, a complete list can
>   be found in POSIX, IEEE Std 1003.1-2003, Base Definitions, Issue 6, in
>   the definition of the term “Memory Synchronization”. For other thread
>   packages, more relaxed or more strict rules may apply.